# Rule engine that stores rules in a property file or in the database

Tags: open-source, java

I am new to rule engines. I need an **open source Java based** Rule engine for my project. I want to store rules in a property file or in the database.

I checked [easyrules](http://www.easyrules.org/) rule engine. It provides 3 ways to define rules-

- implements `Rule` interface
- Extends `BasicRule` class
- Annotations in POJO

I did not find any way to store rules in a property file or in the database.

Is there any similar lightweight API that allows me to do so?

**P.S.** *Number of rules will be between 100-1000.*

Comment: Have you looked at JRuleEngine?  It says rules can be loaded by xml or api, allowing you to save in a db or other. http://jruleengine.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @CPerkins is it open source and is it maven based?

Comment: Yes to open source, dunno about maven.   If that's a requirement, you should put that in the question.